# Jquery Ajax periodic request stops in IE over a long period of continuous run

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

In my application I use jquery ajax to fetch the device data at ~1 second interval. The device has wince os and the web pages are hosted by httpd web server. We could observe the issue after running the device 2 or more days with web clients connected. The IE status bar displays an error “’jqXHR’ is null or not an object” or 'jqXHR'is undefined (in jquery-1.5.2.js, line no. 6819). I am also catching the request errors by using the jquery error function. But this error reported by IE couldn’t be captured by the error function

Line no. 6819 refers to the jquery setTimeout handler, where the ajax jqXHR object is found invalid. I analysed the issue using fiddler and couldn't find any entry with error. But due to the error occurred in browser, there is no further request sent. What I would assume is the request is blocked in IE and it didn't hit the server, hence we couldn't see the entry in fiddler. Once the timeout value set in ajax request is elapsed, the setTimeout handle is executed.

Can anybody guess how the jqXHR object becomes undefined? (This object is not cleared/intialized in any part of the application code. And the requests are sent serially one at a time, after the previous request is complete. This will ensure that the object is not overwritten)

Please find below the SAMPLE CODE, how the Ajax requests are sent and received in my application:

```
            var ajax_timeout = 10000;
            var requests = 0;
            var jqxhr_obj = null;
            var stop_ajax_reqs = 1;
            var ajax_serial_reqs = {
                "None":0,
                "SystemStatus":1,
                "ScreenData":2,
                "Complete":3
            };
            var AjaxReqIndex = ajax_serial_reqs.None;
            var REQUEST_GAP_TIME = 1000;
            var PERIODIC_TIMER_VALUE = 1500;

            function SendAjaxReq(ajaxData)
            {
                jqxhr_obj = $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'DeviceData.asp',
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
                    global: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: ajaxData,
                    dateType: "text",
                    async: true,
                    timeout: ajax_timeout,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function (){requests++;},
                    complete: function(){ requests--; },
                    success: function (data, status, xmlhttp_obj)
                    {
                        $(xmlhttp_obj.responseText).appendTo("body");
                        stop_ajax_reqs = 1;
                    },
                    error: function (xmlhttp_obj, status, error_obj)
                    {          
                        $("<p>Error: "+ status + " - "+requests+" requests active</p>").appendTo("body");       
                        stop_ajax_reqs = 1;       
                    }
                });
            }

            //Send all the requests for this cycle - initiated by setInterval shown below
            function ManageAjaxSerialReqs()
            {
                if (ajax_serial_reqs.None != AjaxReqIndex)
                {
                    //Check if the previous sent ajax request is complete
                    if ((stop_ajax_reqs == 1) && (requests == 0))
                    {
                        switch (AjaxReqIndex)
                        {
                        case ajax_serial_reqs.SystemStatus:    
                            //First request of the cycle
                            SendAjaxReq("FirstReq");
                            stop_ajax_reqs = 0;            
                            AjaxReqIndex = ajax_serial_reqs.ScreenData;
                            break;
                        case ajax_serial_reqs.ScreenData:
                            //Second request of the cycle   
                            SendAjaxReq("SecondReq"); 
                            stop_ajax_reqs = 0;                  
                            AjaxReqIndex = ajax_serial_reqs.Complete;
                            break;    
                        case ajax_serial_reqs.Complete:
                            //Wait until the cycle is complelete ((stop_ajax_reqs == 1) && (requests == 0))
                            AjaxReqIndex = ajax_serial_reqs.None;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Send all the requests until (ajax_serial_reqs.None == AjaxReqIndex)
                    if(ajax_serial_reqs.None != AjaxReqIndex)
                        setTimeout("ManageAjaxSerialReqs()", REQUEST_GAP_TIME);        
                }
            }

            //Periodic timer
            setInterval(function()
            {
                //....do other operation...

                //send periodic requests
                if (ajax_serial_reqs.None == AjaxReqIndex)
                {
                    AjaxReqIndex = ajax_serial_reqs.SystemStatus;
                    ManageAjaxSerialReqs();        
                }

                //....do other operation...

            }, PERIODIC_TIMER_VALUE);
```